# An opensource file upload behaviour for cakephp 2.x?

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, behavior

I tried to use MeioUpload Behavior from [here](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/) but it doesn't really work in cakephp 2.x.

If you can suggest something similar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been using the cakephp2.0 branch of this FileUpload plugin with success:
https://github.com/webtechnick/CakePHP-FileUpload-Plugin

Answer (score 1):

My [FileStorage](https://github.com/burzum/FileStorage) plugin.

Read the instructions carefully and the whole text. It is dead easy to use if you follow them. The behavior will just *validate* but not handle the actual upload. Use the StorageManager and an adapter that matches your requirements (Local FS, S3, Dropbox...). The reason why it works like it is is also described in the readme.

Answer (score 1):

Check this very simple and straight forward way of doing it (read the readme.md thoroughly), did the job for me could even create thumbnails :

https://github.com/malikov/cakephp2.0-image-upload

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is required that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a AJAX-based, multi-file upload plugin, the [AjaxMultiUpload](https://github.com/srs81/CakePHP-AjaxMultiUpload) plugin might be helpful. And it works on CakePHP 2.x.